# How to concat multiple Kotlin Flows sequencially?

Tags: kotlin, merge, concatenation

I'm looking for a way to subscribe to multiple Kotlin Flows sequencially, something similar to rxjs's concat operator. Next Flow should only be subscribed once previous one is completed.

Example:

```
val flow1 = flowOf(0,1,2).onEach { delay(10) }
val flow2 = flowOf(3,4,5).onEach { delay(10) }

runBlocking{
    listOf(flow1,flow2)
        .merge()
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .collect()
}

-> prints 0,3,1,4,2,5 // Flow order is not preserved
```

I imagine a solution could be to replace merge() with concat(), but this operator sadly doesn't exist in Kotlin Flows

```
val flow1 = flowOf(0,1,2).onEach { delay(10) }
val flow2 = flowOf(3,4,5).onEach { delay(10) }

runBlocking{
    listOf(flow1,flow2)
        .concat()
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .collect()
}

-> prints 0,1,2,3,4,5 // Flow order is now preserved
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [flattenConcat](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flatten-concat.html).

It has a `Flow<Flow<T>>` receiver, but you could easily make a `Flow` out of your list of flows, for instance using `list.asFlow()`. Or you could create a `Flow` directly instead of a list by using `flowOf` instead of `listOf`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, do you have a code example to illustrate how I could make a Flow out of a list of flows please?

Comment: @Verrick Simply `flowOf(flow1, flow2)`?

Comment: This, or `list.asFlow()` if you had constructed the list somewhere else already. I updated the answer